# How to go about leasing a car in Germany?

Tags: germany, car, financial, lease

I will lease a car in Germany.

What do I need in order to get it?

What would be the procedures, documents needed?

And last question is: I don't want to do any payment, of any percentage of the car. I was in the https://www.sixt-leasing.de/

It looks like it is possible, to "just lease". Is that really possible, or do I need to do downpayment of let's say 20%.

Comment: Did you ask your employer? I believe company car purchase and/or leasing schemes are quite popular in Germany

Comment: Yes, I have heard about it. But I want to lease on my own.

Comment: You would usually go to a car brand shop (_Autohaus_), like a _BMW Niederlassung_ or smiliar and talk to them to make a leasing contract. Those work for new cars. It might be cheaper and easier to buy a used car though.